# res.render() not being displayed

Tags: javascript, express

I have a problem when a client tries to log in. The request gets verified and the server answer with res.render. I can see the site I want it to render in the response, however the actual site the client is looking at doesn't change.

Server

```
router.post('/login', validFields('email', 'password'), (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.email.indexOf('@') === -1) {
        return res.status(400).end();
    }

    models.ModelUser.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (user) {
             user.authenticate(req.body.password, (err, matches) => {
                if (err) { 
                    return res.status(500).end();
                }
                if (!matches) { 
                    return res.status(400).json({success: false, error: 'Incorrect password.'}); 
                }

                user.password = undefined;
                req.session.user = user;
                req.session.loggedIn = true;
                res.status(200).render('user/apps');
            });
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({success: false, error: 'User not found.'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well if the server sends the correct response but the client doesn't work correctly it means the problem is in the client-side code, don't you think? But it sounds like you should be redirecting the client to the new URL instead.

Comment: @GuyIncognito True, but I am not sure how to do it. Do I change the window.location?

Comment: Yes, something like `res.status(400).json({success: true, redirect: "http://whatever/url/you/want"})` and `window.location.href = response.redirect` in the client (or whatever contains the response data.)